# translate property in NativeScript Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I use this code to move a GridLayout in ***NativeScript + Vue***:

```
this.$refs.cover.nativeView.animate({ translate: { x: 0, y: 100} } )
```

*My question is this:* since we do not access to translate property of CSS in NativeScript, How can I set my Layout to the position: ( `top: 100` ) , just **ONLY** by setting **CSS**.

*or if I want to ask more precisely:* Which property would be manipulated by nativeView.animate to put my Layout in `translate: { x: 0, y: 100 }` position?

Comment: The properties are translateX and translateY. While using CSS, apply transform (`transform: translate(0, 100); `);

Comment: @Manoj thanks a lot, yeah it works; I was thought that all usable  CSS properties are those are listed here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling,

could you share a link of complete list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation related CSS attributes are defined in the [Animation with CSS](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation-css) docs.

`translate: { x: 0, y: 100 }`: Operates on translateX and translateY attributes, with CSS same will be

```
transform: translate(0, 100);
```